# In-app Billing default currency android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

My problem is that: i have created products in google developer console to my app and the default currency is in HUF (this is hungarian currency), but i want to set up the products in default USD! How can i change the default currency in developer console?

Comment: Isn't Hungary in Europe? If so, it should display EUR, not HUF...

Comment: yes Hungary is in Europe, but it displays HUF

Comment: Funny. Isn't Hungary passed to **€**, yet?

Comment: 8 years later and still can't set dollars... greetings from Poland

Answer (score 0):

When an app is uploaded to Google Play, you will be asked to set a default price for the app in your home currency. This price will be used for all countries/regions which you do not manually override. **Additionally, you can set a price for each app separately in individual currency per country.** The prices you set in one currency are completely independent of prices in other currencies.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138412

Comment: And after that i can't change the currency? I found this : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6140453?hl=hu